# Иконка Файла Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, иконки

Как изменить иконку файла. Visual Studio C++ 2017.
Я сделал проект для себя, откомпилировал а и файл выглядит уродливо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы файл имел красивый вид, например как еиоит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свою иконку создал но где настроить чтоб она была в компилирована.?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Ничего не понял - иконку какого файла надо - исполняемого, или проекта, или еще какого-то? И что такое "еиоит"?

Comment: Да нужно изменить иконку исполняемого файла. Точнее настроить визуалку чтобы она сразу создавала файл с нужной иконкой.

Comment: инструкция по ссылке не работает у меня в файле ресурсов у меня нет иконок. Тем более если у меня например openGL приложение то файла ресурсов в проекте и вовсе не существует.

Comment: Что значит "у меня нет иконок"? Так добавьте иконку в ресурсы, за вас это никто не сделает. Файл ресурсов будет создан автоматически если его нет. Инструкция по ссылке работает.

Comment: В вопрос добавил скрин файла ресурсов. я бросал туда иконки но толку 0 .

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка, надо rc-файл добавить, а в него иконку

Comment: Pavel Gridin Сработало огромное спасибо вам,и всем кто участвовал. Pavel Gridin  Добавите пожалуйста етот комментарий как ответ. Коротко и понятно.

Comment: Pavel Gridin Сработало огромное спасибо вам,и всем кто участвовал. Pavel Gridin  Добавите пожалуйста етот комментарий как ответ. Коротко и понятно.